# assigning anonymous functions to buttons

Tags: javascript

When i use if statements to determine whether a user has viewed the form before, it breaks my whole code.Originally, my code just removed a child, and set the display of the next DIV to "block".This worked perfectly fine. all my variables saved properly in the end, etc.

However, since I added these checks to the buttons, everything has gone haywire.

I've tried using different mixes of appendChild, removeChild, and style.display methods. I even booted it up in notepad++ to help me visualize.

```
document.getElementById("newUser").addEventListener("click", function(parent, start, personal){
parent.removeChild(start);
document.getElementById.style.display="block";
});

document.getElementById("toGeneral").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(reUser === 0){
        oPersonal;
        document.getElementById("general").style.display="block";
    } else if(reUser === 1){
        oPersonal;
        parent.appendChild(oShowInfo);
    } else {
        window.alert("Whoops this function is in progress");
    }
    return oPersonal;
});
```

I want my forms to be editable at the end of the form. 
In one test (not this one). I was able to move back and forth between pages, but it would stop the loops that kept my variables up.

This one is using the oldChild = parent.removeChild() method to fix that, which may also be part of the issue.

**Note: variables such as

oPersonal

reUser

parent

are stored just above this code at the beginning of the page loop.

New code:

```
document.getElementById("newUser").addEventListener("click", function(){
parent.removeChild(start);
document.getElementById.style.display="block";
});

document.getElementById("toGeneral").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(reUser === 0){
        oPersonal;
        document.getElementById("general").style.display="block";
    } else if(reUser === 1){
        oPersonal;
        parent.appendChild(oShowInfo);
    } else {
        window.alert("Whoops this function is in progress");
    }
    return oPersonal;
});
```

Comment: Please add the `reUser`  variable declaration and what is the value it gets.`it breaks my whole code` Please specify what is the issue you are facing

Comment: Returning from event listener handler functions is rarely useful. The handler is called from the event queue, and the return value is thrown to the bit space. Also you can't pass arbitrary arguments to event handlers like that, the only argument passed is the event object.

Comment: on the last DIV (the pages containing input fields that pass their inputs to objects). The event handler also returns reUser++;

Comment: @patient.porpoise There's no place in any code where you could receive a return value from an event listener handler function which was set by `addEventListener`. I'd recommend to read about event listeners at [QuirksMode](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in this code. First, your click event's handler can not take 3 args like this. When an event is triggered, only this event is passed to the function. So your code should looks like :

```
document.getElementById("newUser").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    let element = event.target;
    let parent = element.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(element);
    //Next line is wrong since getElementById is a function and should take args
    //document.getElementById.style.display="block";
});
```

Then on your second element's click event handler, it seems like you are trying to use parent which is not in the same scope.
Also the return statement is strange, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: ahh yes, the extra arguments were part of my experiments to make the function recognize my pages. basically, I am taking information about a person's vehicle over several pages (Div's with id's). Each page has looping object that listens for key events. which works fine. when each button has only one task. (removing current DIV, and changing the next DIV's style to display="block" to show it. When i use the if else event listeners here. it seems to work (without the arguments) as long as i'm removing/appending. but doesn't remember the input loops on the way back.